# load_dotenv .env not working when running pyinstaller executable from path search

Tags: python, path, scripting, pyinstaller

I have this small python .exe created with `pyinstaller` that use `load_dotenv`'s .env to load in some environment variables like so: [image]

It runs perfectly when I run the executable directly. For example by doing  `.\auto-log.exe` from the program directory

Then I added the program path to the Path environment variable so that I run it anywhere by entering the executable's name `auto-log`. Windows 10 manages to find my program correctly but the environment variables in the `.env` file aren't get loaded and return `None`

I'm wondering what's causing the issue and how I can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

After an hour or 2 of debugging, I realized the process by doing the path search method, started in a different directory rather than the actual location where the executable is located.

```
C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Local\Temp\{TEMP-DIR}
```

Thus, the `load_dotenv` couldn't find the relative .env